# TensorFlow error: TensorShape() must have the same rank

Tags: python, theano, tensorflow

```
def compileActivation(self, net, layerNum):
    variable = net.x if layerNum == 0 else net.varArrayA[layerNum - 1]
    #print tf.expand_dims(net.dropOutVectors[layerNum], 1)

    #print net.varWeights[layerNum]['w'].get_shape().as_list()

    z = tf.matmul((net.varWeights[layerNum]['w']), (variable * (tf.expand_dims(net.dropOutVectors[layerNum], 1) if self.dropout else 1.0))) + tf.expand_dims(net.varWeights[layerNum]['b'], 1)

    a = self.activation(z, self.pool_size)
    net.varArrayA.append(a)
```

I am running an activation function which computes `z` and passes it into a sigmoid activation.
When I try to execute the above function, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([Dimension(-2)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) must have the same rank
```

The theano equivalent for computing `z` is working just fine:

```
z = T.dot(net.varWeights[layerNum]['w'], variable * (net.dropOutVectors[layerNum].dimshuffle(0, 'x') if self.dropout else 1.0)) + net.varWeights[layerNum]['b'].dimshuffle(0, 'x')
```

Comment: That code looks syntactically correct, but it appears that some object in `net` has a corrupt shape. In particular `TensorShape([Dimension(-2)])` should never occur, and this is tested for in TensorFlow 0.7.0, so if you upgrade you may get a more helpful error message.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mihir,

**When I encountered this problem it was because my placeholders were the wrong size in my feed dictionary.** Also you should know how to run the graph in a session. [tf.Session.run(fetches, feed_dict=None)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/client.html#Session)

Here's my code to make the [placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder)

```
# Note this place holder is for the input data feed-dict definition
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, FLAGS.InputLayer))
# Not sure yet what this will be used for. 
desired_output_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, FLAGS.OutputLayer))
```

Here's my fill feed dictionary function:

```
def feel_feed_funct(data_sets_train, input_pl, output_pl):
  ti_feed, dto_feed = data_sets_train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)

  feed_dict = {
    input_pl: ti_feed,
    output_pl: dto_feed
  }
  return feed_dict
```

Later I do this:

```
# Fill a feed dictionary with the actual set of images and labels
# for this particular training step.
feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(data_sets.train, input_placeholder, desired_output_placeholder)
```

Then to run the session and fetch the outputs I have this line

```
_, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```